# FBSDKShareLinkContent not working for few links on iOS

Tags: ios, fbsdk

Our app has functionality where user can share the posts from one of our FB page feed.

It works perfectly fine for any kind of link if device has FB native app installed but if it doesn't then it only works for few links. I couldn't understand why it is happening.

**Link works successfully:**

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/bigfishgames/videos/10154487015659966/"];

---

**Link not working:**

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/bigfishgames/photos/a.89705929965.104855.10172494965/10154513459844966/?type=3"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, after filing bug to facebook they have fixed this issue.